# The middleware doesn't start automatically, and it doesn't write to Serilog

Tags: c#, nunit, middleware, serilog

Here, I'm attaching the code inside the middleware:

```
namespace ...
{
    public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            Log.Information("::::::MyMiddleware executing");

            try
            {
                 _logger.LogInformation("MyMiddleware executing..");
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }
        }

        private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message + "ERROR Exc...");

            Log.Error(ex.Message + "ERROR Exc...");

            var errorid = Activity.Current?.Id ?? context.TraceIdentifier;
            var customerError = $"ErrorId-{errorid}: Message-Some kind of error happened in the API";
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerError);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }

    public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, here in the configuration:

```
webBuilder.Configure(app =>
{
    app.UseMyMiddleware();
});
```

Here's how I set up the logger inside the NUnit test:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.File("logs\\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day) // Log su file
                    .CreateLogger();
```

I'm noticing that the middleware isn't working at all. The configuration is within a project that will later need to connect to other projects. So, I would like it to be automatically configured as I have attached above.

To test this code, I'm using NUnit tests. I've tried throwing an exception, but it doesn't enter the middleware.

Does anyone have any advice or a solution to offer?

Comment: Can you just start your app and debug it?

Comment: Q2: what do you test in your unit test? What is your arrange?

Comment: So, the application starts correctly, and I can debug it. However, in theory, as written in the code, it should go through "MyMiddleware executing" and write the log, but whether it goes into an exception or just during startup, it doesn't enter that part. In theory, from what I understand (I'm a junior looking to become proficient in this field), it should start in a standalone mode when it encounters an exception and write the logs for me. With debugging, it doesn't go through that part at all, and honestly, apart from checking the configuration multiple times, I don't know what else to do

Comment: Can you share your `Program.cs` or `StartUp.cs` ?  specifically the section where you have configured this `ILogger`  that you are injecting in your `MyMiddleware`.

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k keep in mind that this will be an application that can be attached to others, so the program.cs will simply need to call this application (everything works without any issues, in fact, I've tested it, and it works perfectly).
As for the loggers, I'll place them on top as an additional feature. I don't think that's the issue because it's writing the logs.

Comment: Okay from the code snippets shared I don't see any issue yet, And you say on debugging of the app " it doesn't go through that part at all" able to share a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k Hello, you see, the issue was that in Nunit tests, you can't execute middleware with HttpContext because Nunit tests run in a separate context from the code. So, I presume this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Nunit tests cannot access HttpContext because they are isolated. In fact, when I made an HTTP request, they worked correctly. So, I had to manually invoke them within the tests by making calls.